# Subsetting rows by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe ('df') and the first column is a timestamp.  I successfully converted that timestamp from that milliseconds since Unix epoch thing to a date like this "2020-02-18 13:00:00" (which is 1:00 pm on February 18th, 2020) with the following code:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='ms')
```

I'm trying to subset to just all of the rows from 2020-02-17 but this code:

```
df_1day = df[(df['Time'] == '2020-02-17')]
```

only returns the row at midnight (2020-02-17 00:00:00)

I'm sorry if the answer is somewhere else in this site, or the internet in general, but TIA for any help.

Not sure of protocol if I answer my own questions but I'm doing this edit to include lines of code that solved my issue--even though I'm pretty sure there's an easier way of doing this

```
## Create new column with 'Time' as a string
df['Day'] = df['Time'].astype(str)

## Take only the first 10 characters of the string (which would be date only)
df['Day'] = df['Day'].str[:10]

## Create dataframe subset based on values in the new column
df_1day = df[(df['Day'] == '2020-02-17')]
```

Comment: You need to extract the date portion from each row, and compare *that* to the desired date.  Another possibility is to check to see whether the `df` date is withing the desired time range.

Comment: putting @Prune's comment in code, something like `df[(df['Time'].dt.date == '2020-02-17')] `

Comment: Each row in the df is an hour and I've checked to make sure that there are 24 rows/hours for that date.  Unfortunately, the code you provided returns now rows and just the column names.  How would I go about subsetting just the date?  Counting the characters from the left?